# C++ Delete a node from binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

This is the place where I am trying to solve this particular problem:
http://mycodeschool.com/work-outs/binary-search-trees/7

In case the node to be deleted has both children, the strategy to adopt is to replace that node with the maximum value in its left subtree (lets call it MAX_LEFT). Then you can simply delete the node MAX_LEFT. This strategy is also discussed in our video for this problem.

I am trying to solve this problem by below code. But there are some issues and I am not getting the expected output.

```
struct Node
  {
     int data;
     struct Node* left;
     struct Node* right;
  }

Node* FindMax(Node* root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    return NULL;

    while(root->right != NULL)
    {
        root = root->right;
    }
    return root;
}
Node* DeleteNodeInBST(Node* root,int data)
{
    if(root==NULL) return root;
    else if(data<=root->data) 
        root->left = DeleteNodeInBST(root->left, data);
    else if (data> root->data)
        root->right = DeleteNodeInBST(root->right, data);
    else
    {
        //No child
        if(root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL)
        {
            delete root;
            root = NULL;   
        }
        //One child 
        else if(root->right == NULL)
        {
            Node* temp = root;
            root= root->left;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if(root->left == NULL)
        {
            Node* temp = root;
            root= root->right;
            delete temp;
        }
        //two child
        else
        {
            Node* temp = FindMax(root->left);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->left = DeleteNodeInBST(root->left, temp->data);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Try running in a debugger, and step through the code line by line. Also, if you have a problem with unexpected output, then please show the actual as well as the expected output. It would also be very useful to see *how* you use these functions (i.e. try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: instead of writing " But there are some issues" describe what you entered, what you expect and what you are getting.

Comment: This is the place where I am trying to solve this particular problem:
http://mycodeschool.com/work-outs/binary-search-trees/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part

```
if(data<=root->data)
    root->left = DeleteNodeInBST(root->left, data);
else
    ...
```

will step down to the left subtree also when `data` is *equal* to the current node `root`. As a result you will *never* get to the third `else`. Try replacing `<=` with `<`.

Answer (score 3):

In the code segment below, after 2 *else if* statement, final *else* statement is never executed, because there is no other possibility:

```
 else if(data<=root->data) 
        root->left = DeleteNodeInBST(root->left, data);
 else if (data> root->data)
        root->right = DeleteNodeInBST(root->right, data);
 else
        ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I have to remove "=" in "else if(data<=root->data)" and then it works.